# how to convert epoch time to human readable time in milliseconds

Tags: r, epoch

I have a data which has epoch time and I need to extract the human readable time in year, month, day, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.

epoch time before conversion:
1517166673385

After conversion I need it to be in this format:
20180128191113385

I have written the following function and it works well, but it takes a long time. I am searching for a faster function because I have thousands of files to process.

```
getDTI<- function(echotime){
  DTItemp<-as.POSIXct(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(substr(echotime,1,10)),  origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
  DTI<-paste0(substr(DTItemp,1,4),substr(DTItemp,6,7),substr(DTItemp,9,10),substr(DTItemp,12,13),substr(DTItemp,15,16),substr(DTItemp,18,19),substr(test$STIME,11,13))

return(DTI)
```

}

Comment: what do you expect as your output?

Comment: 1517166673385 > 20180128191113385 (year, month, day, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 1517166673385
 paste0(format(as.POSIXct(a/1000,origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),sprintf("%03d",a%%1000))
```

[1] "20180128191113385"
 in a function form:

```
fun=function(a){
paste0(format(as.POSIXct(a/1000,origin="1970-01-01", 
tz="GMT"),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),sprintf("%03d",a%%1000))
}


 d=c(1517166673385, 1517701556075)

fun(d)
[1] "20180128191113385" "20180203234556075"
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.
There is still a problem.
your function gives 20181313142597 while it should give 20180203131402597

Comment: for which number??@NatheerAlabsi

Comment: zero is missing meaning it gives one less number in some cases

Comment: @NatheerAlabsi can you give an example where zero is missing?

Comment: epochTime: 1517701556075    

After conversion: 2018020323455675    

It should give: 20180203234556075